# Making an ISO bootable in VBox

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, iso, mkisofs

I've created a custom ISO file from the original one via [mkisofs](https://wiki.osdev.org/Mkisofs) , but now I'm unable to boot it in VirtualBox 5.2 :

```
FATAL : Couldn't read from the boot medium ! System halted.
```

And here's the command I've used to create the ISO:

```
sudo mkisofs  -o ubuntu.iso test2/
```

I've just replaced the `casper/filesystem.squashfs` file (although I needed to update the `casper/filesystem.squashfs.gpg` and `/md5sums.txt` but those are not my concern here, because the problem is with the ISO file itself.The VBox even cannot boot the kernel , let alone the filesystem integrity check).

The origianal ISO file is : `ubuntu-18.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso`

Any help is much appreciated

---

**EDIT:** Surely the problem is with **mkisofs** because I tried making an ISO file out of an extracted ISO (the original one) without any slightest manipulation , but I got that error again.
Looks like just a **boot** flag is missing , but I don't know how to add it.

Comment: You did not mention whether you really used `mkisofs`. Note that ubuntu delivers `mkisofs` as a symlink to the defective genisofs. As long as you do not explain how you used `mkisofs` it is not possible to help you...

Comment: @schily Requested information added to the post.

Answer (score 1):

A recent man page is at:

http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man8/mkisofs.8.html

and if you check your command line, you see tha you did not use any of the options that make a CD bootable.

If you installed the original `mkisofs` you have a file `README.eltorito` that contains e.g. this command line example:

```
mkisofs -V MYVOL -iso-level 4 -R -b boot/grub/stage2_eltorito -no-emul-boot \
    -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o myvol.iso thisdir
```

and this one:

```
mkisofs -V MYVOL -iso-level 4 -R -b boot/grub/stage2_eltorito -no-emul-boot \
    -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
    -eltorito-alt-boot -eltorito-platform efi -b boot/grub/boot.efi \
    -no-emul-boot
    -o myvol.iso thisdir
```

as an EFI example. You however need to know where to get the boot images from...

**Important:** the file names are examples. You need to use the right really existing file names that match the file tree you like to turn into a bootable CD.

And BTW: Since `genisoimage` is from May 2004, it does not yet support `-eltorito-platform efi`.

A recent version of `mkisofs` is always inside the `schilytools` tarball at:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/

If you have a working ISO image, you could run `isodebug -i xxx.iso` (replace xxx.iso with your image name) to get the mkisofs command lineoptions that have been used with that image. But note that this only works if xxx.iso has been created with the original mkisofs program.

In any case, if you got the boot tree from somewhere, I am sure that these know which files are the files you need to tell mkisofs as boot image files.

Comment: After running that , I got this error : ```genisoimage: option '-eltorito' is ambiguous; possibilities: '-eltorito-boot' '-eltorito-alt-boot' '-eltorito-catalog'```.

Comment: After removing the option ```-eltorito platform efi``` it starts working but it couldn't find the ```boot/grub/stage2_eltorito``` file : ```genisoimage: Uh oh, I cant find the boot image 'boot/grub/stage2_eltorito' ! ```

Comment: So you are not using mkisofs but the defective fork that is at the state from May 2004. BTW: My example does not list an option `-eltorito`.

Comment: Oh my bad .That was an error when I copy-pasted it.I just removed the backslashes and the **dash** was also deleted accidentally. But what about the original **mkisofs** ? Where Can I find it ? And what about the file ```'boot/grub/stage2_eltorito'``` ?

Comment: As already mentioned, the real filenames used by your boot tree depends on the boot tree.

Comment: But I haven't such a file in my system : ```stage2_eltorito```.

Comment: ... you're supposed to give the name of the actual file in the iso, this depends on your distro.

Comment: @Panki There's no **eltorito** at all in the whole ISO. ```sudo find .  | grep -i elto``` returns nothing.

Comment: Here's the [ISO structure](https://pastebin.com/7SFpiprP) . I've used **EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI** , **EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi**  and **boot/grub/efi.img** but none of them were able to boot the ISO.

Comment: And also [stage2_eltorito](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Images.html) needs two modules : **cdboot.img** and **core.img**.None of them are present in my ISO.

Comment: Is there no help from the people that provided the boot filesystem tree?